# Anyone knows how to solve npm start error: Error: assets.flatMap is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

I tried to dowload the updated version of node.js but when I do node -v I still have the older version.
Not sure which step follow. I hope someone can give me a dummy step by step update node explanation

➜  55 - Face Detection Censorship git:(master) ✗ npm start

> pixelated-face@1.0.0 start /home/XXX/code/XXX/javascript-notes/exercises/55 - Face Detection Censorship
> parcel face.html

ℹ️ Server running at http://localhost:1234
 Build failed.
Error: assets.flatMap is not a function
TypeError: assets.flatMap is not a function
at Transformation.runPipelines (/home/XXX/code/XXX/javascript-notes/exercises/55 - Face Detection Censorship/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Transformation.js:366:131)
Parcel is shutting down...

Comment: What is your node version? check with `node -v`

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with:

**sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable**

To upgrade to latest version (and not current stable) version, you can use

**sudo n latest**

Fix PATH:

**sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs-legacy     # fix /usr/bin/node**

To undo:

**sudo n rm 6.0.0     # replace number with version of Node that was installed
sudo npm uninstall -g n**

You may need to restart your terminal to see the updated node version.

Answer (score 0):

just use NVM for updating node.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm